# Android Google Map API V2 - Error Inflating Class Fragment

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-fragments, sdk

I have been following Googles guide to making an app that allows you to view an app on an Android phone. I have followed many tutorials, but always end up with the same error! I have also searched around the web and figured my error is something to do with the "fragment". Here are my files:

#### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.theapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.theapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.theapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.theapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>     

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="--REMOVED--"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.theapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

I am using Android 2.3. Here is the log cat messages:

```
04-02 22:43:45.890: D/AndroidRuntime(23773): Shutting down VM
04-02 22:43:45.890: W/dalvikvm(23773): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x40018578)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{com.example.theapp/com.example.theapp.MainActivity}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at com.example.theapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    ... 11 more
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.theapp-1.apk]
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-02 22:43:45.898: E/AndroidRuntime(23773):    ... 19 more
04-02 22:55:53.289: D/AndroidRuntime(23942): Shutting down VM
04-02 22:55:53.289: W/dalvikvm(23942): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.theapp/com.example.theapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at com.example.theapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    ... 11 more
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.theapp-2.apk]
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-02 22:55:53.304: E/AndroidRuntime(23942):    ... 19 more
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     package com.example.theapp;

      import android.app.Activity;
              import android.os.Bundle;

             public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

                  @Override
             protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                   }
                }
```

and in manifest add one more meta tag below previous one.

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Api key" />
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Your code worked. However I am having some more problems, I am trying to achieve buttons that allow you to change its location such as: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc", however he does not use "extend FragmentActivity", how may I work around this? I currently have a map on one page, I cannot add a button above the map. It just shows the map, else its on top of the map. I have created a separate question. Thank you. Heres the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842732/android-google-map-api-v2-buttons-above-fragment

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, You should include android-support-v4.jar file from Android SDK folder "sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar". If You dont have that file, in Your SDK Manager install Android Support Library, which is found under Extras.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have already included this file, however now I have another problem. I would be grateful if you could take a look. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842732/android-google-map-api-v2-buttons-above-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following steps:

1. In android manifest you have the NETWORK STATE permission like this

   < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
2. In android manifest make sure you have the following code as well-

   ```
     <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value=" YOUR KEY HERE" />

    <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
   ```
3. Lastly if you are testing your application  on android API 5.x then make sure you modify your map code like this-

Instead of this

```
 map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

write this

```
map = getMapFragment().getMap();
```

and add a small method like this

```
private MapFragment getMapFragment() {
        FragmentManager fm = null;

        Log.d("", "sdk: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        Log.d("", "release: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Log.d("", "using getFragmentManager");
            fm = getFragmentManager();
        } else {
            Log.d("", "using getChildFragmentManager");
            fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        }

        return (MapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    }
```

And make sure for step 3 your min sdk version in your manifest file is 17 like this

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```