# Android Google Map API V2 - Buttons above fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, button, android-fragments

I have managed to get a map to show on the screen. I am trying to create buttons above the map and then add actions to this. E.g. the button will change the location of the map. I am basically trying to adapt my code to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc. However, I am using "extends Fragment Activity" which messes everything up.

My problem: I cannot create a button above the map, it is placed inside the map. I am trying to create a button above the map, and assign code so I can move to a location on the map etc. Here is my code:

#### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.theapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener
{

    Button button;
    TextView text;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        text.setText("The button worked!");

    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/map"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

From the code, my app displays a button on the map and a text view. When you click the button, its meant to change the text, but it doesn't do anything. I have researched tutorials and by the looks of it, I will have to create multiple fragments?

Question: How would I be able to create a button on that page, that will then pin point the user on the map?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: there are markers infowindows which you might find useful check them

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @Raghunandan, I have looked them up. However I cannot actually use them unless I have an API above 11. Is there a way around this? I added this under my activity       myMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
       myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

Comment: you can use them using support library for backward compatibility

Comment: @Raghunandan how would it be done using the code used in the comment above yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting any functionality to the Button... You should use

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text.setText("that's how you do it!");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. But where would I place this code? What part of the Main Activity? If I place this inside onCreate, I will only be able to use it once

Comment: No you wont be using it only once...You can put it in "onCreate"

Answer (score 0):

You need not to worry about  "FragmentActivity"  until and unless you use fragment class.
  Just use this as normal Activity. it will work well.

```
    package com.example.theapp;

     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.TextView;

       public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener
     {

       Button button;
       TextView text;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
         text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     }

        @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        text.setText("The button worked!");

      }
       }
```